# get_the_tags doesn't works?

Tags: plugin-development

I am creating a plugin in which a user will submit their email address and favourite tags. When publishing a new post, if the post has tags similar to the user's favourite tags, an email will be sent to the user. For this I need to compare new post tags with the user's favourite tags.

On basis of its definition `get_the_tags($postId)` should return an array of `post_tags` but it doesn't. I don't know what to do!

```
add_action('publish_post', array( $myClass ,'wp_send_emailToUser' ), 10, 2);
class customFunction{
function wp_send_emailToUser( $postId, $post ) {
    $posttags = get_the_tags($postid);
    if ($posttags) {
       //...do sth
    }else{
       error_log( "@ tags are empty,post id={$postId}" );
    }
}
```

The new post I published has some tags but it goes to the else part and print `error_log("@ tags are empty, post id={$postId}");` in my debug.log file. I searched a lot but didn't find anything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/266999](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/266999/wordpress-post-tags-get-the-tags-has-tag)

I found the problem in the above link , I should use set_object_terms becaus tags will not be with the post in publish_post.

Comment: But I was able to get the tags with your code also :)